# how to call stored procedure using asp.net vb code required

Tags: asp.net

i have stored procedure called dissumbio this will return some value

now i want to call this in my asp.net program and returned value should display in my textbox

my code is as follows

```
Dim admdate As String

admdate = Mid(txtadmdate.Text, 4, 2) + "/" + Left(txtadmdate.Text, 2) + "/20" + Right(txtadmdate.Text, 2)

Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strId", txthospno.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strfromdate", admdate)

cmd.Connection = sqlConn2
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

this is arjent and please help

thanks in advance

shubha

Comment: you're not specifying the name of your stored procedure. Try `Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("dissumbio")`

Comment: What are the value/values you returing from your sp?

Answer (score 1):

ExecuteNonQuery will retrun only the number of rows affected...so in your case if your stored procedure return a value you have to use
 `

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strId", txthospno.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strfromdate", admdate)

cmd.Connection = sqlConn2
sqlConn2.Open()
value= Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
```

`

Comment: hi i tried bt i am getting error as Input string was not in a correct format. Please suggest thanks for ur response

Comment: if the SP return value is string than you can use               Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) instead of Convert.ToInt32

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retrieve data, you shoud use [ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`

Please hava look at this article about  [Execute a Stored Procedure that Returns Rows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7125bke.aspx#Y1824)

```
Dim sqlConnection1 As New SqlConnection("Your Connection String")
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim reader As SqlDataReader

cmd.CommandText = "StoredProcedureName"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1

sqlConnection1.Open()

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
' Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.

sqlConnection1.Close()
```

Comment: hi i tried bt it will giving error as ExecuteReader: CommandText property has not been initialized pls suggest thank you 4 ur response

Comment: @user1702346:Do you have the `Dim cmd As New SqlCommand` line??